# Density function graph

Tags: plotting

[image]
I want to plot density function graphs of Ailamujia distribution pdf and acd on mathematica software .

Comment: Why does `n` appear in (1) but not in (2)? And why is it a free variable in (1)?

Comment: Please post your attempts at *Mathematica* code.

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Define the distribution using [`ProbabilityDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProbabilityDistribution.html)

```
AilamujiaDistribution[θ_] = ProbabilityDistribution[
   4*x*θ^2*E^(-2*θ*x), {x, 0, Infinity},
   Assumptions -> {θ > 0}];
```

Then the distribution can be used like the built-in distributions.

```
dist = AilamujiaDistribution[θ];

PDF[dist, x]

(* Piecewise[{{(4*x*θ^2)/E^(2*x*θ), 
       x > 0}}, 0] *)

Plot3D[PDF[dist, x], {x, 0, 5}, {θ, 0, 2},
 PlotRange -> All,
 PlotPoints -> 25,
 MaxRecursion -> 5,
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {x, θ, PDF})]
```

[image]

```
CDF[dist, x]

(* Piecewise[
   {{(-1 + E^(2*x*θ) - 2*x*θ)/
         E^(2*x*θ), x > 0}}, 0] *)

Plot3D[CDF[dist, x], {x, 0, 5}, {θ, 0, 2},
 PlotRange -> All,
 PlotPoints -> 25,
 MaxRecursion -> 5,
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {x, θ, CDF})]
```

[image]

```
Mean[dist]

(* 1/θ *)

Variance[dist]

(* 1/(2 θ^2) *)

StandardDeviation[dist] //
 Simplify[#, DistributionParameterAssumptions[dist]] &

(* 1/(Sqrt[2] θ) *)
```

**EDIT:** This distribution is equivalent to `GammaDistribution[2, 1/(2θ)]`

```
PDF[dist, x] === PDF[GammaDistribution[2, 1/(2 θ)], x]

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I have the same question as @m_goldberg, you may try the following code to play with. You can play with different values of `eta` in `f[x_]`:

```
ClearAll[f, F, tet, eta];
Manipulate[
 f[x_] := 4 x tet^2 Exp[-2 tet eta];
 F[x_] := 1 - (1 + 2 tet x) Exp[-2 tet x];
Plot[{f[x], F[x]}, {x, 0, 1}],
{eta, 0, 10},
{tet, 0, 10}
]
```